# Looking for a way to receive a rest notification when data updated on Socrata

Tags: listener, socrata, soda

Do any features exist in Socrata whereby my cloud-based app can receive a REST notification when new data is added to a (specific) dataset?

I could of course poll Socrata - via a REST request - to check this, but it would be much more efficient if there was a hook that I could, say, register a listener with to be notified when new data arrived in a dataset.

If this does not exist within Socrata, I could simulate this by creating a service that would poll Socrata and notify my app accordingly. Perhaps such a service exists?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Colin Goldberg

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about sounds like a [Webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook), and unfortunately its not something we support in our platform (yet). It's on our roadmap, and I'd love to have it myself, but unfortunately its not far enough along for me to have an availability date I can give you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do hope there is some way to accelerate this feature. In my case I would like to integrate it with my new product Ritc (www.ritc.io), so that rules could be invoked in real time (or near real time) when new data is added in a dataset.

Regards

Comment: Nice product! We can use more apps like that, I've been playing with Huginn lately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have not heard of Huginn - I will have to look it up. If you have any need for beta testers when the 'webhooks' become available, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: 2 years later, is this still a no-go from Socrata? By the way, great article on Huginn. For the others: https://dev.socrata.com/blog/2017/03/29/conditional-notifications-with-huginn.html